# iPhone -> which is the last delegate method before leaving a view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPhone application and a `navigationController`. I do this:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyVievController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
[myVC release];
```

Doing this, I will have a "back" button in the upper left corner in `MyViewController`. Clicking it, the screen will go back to the previous ViewController.

What I need is the last called function in `MyViewController`, after I clicked the back button, because I have to save data in this ViewController before leaving the view.

Which delegate method do I have to use?

Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `viewWillDisappear`.